# Why did Magento remove RefundOrderInventoryObserver.php from Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

Magento had a useful observer class **`RefundOrderInventoryObserver`**, which was used to observe **`sales_order_creditmemo_save_after`** event.

The class was part of Magento core until Magento 2.1.x, but from **Magento 2.2**, it has been removed.

Can someone tell me why Magento team dropped this from Magento Core?

Is there any alternative to this class so that I can make some customizations when a credit memo is generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still there in:

```
vendor/magento/module-sales-inventory/Observer/RefundOrderInventoryObserver.php
```